# Experimental proof for isospin conservation of strong interaction

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, strong-force, isospin-symmetry

I am having a surprisingly hard time to find direct experimental results for the (approx.) conservation of isospin in strong interactions. The canonical examples seem to be $\omega \! \to 3\pi^0$ and $\rho^0 \! \to 2\pi^0$. But the former is also forbidden by charge conjugation and I failed to find a measured limit for the latter. In fact, I would prefer measurements that approximately reproduce expected branching ratios, such as $\Delta^0 \! \to p \pi^-$ vs. $\Delta^0 \! \to n \pi^0$, but again, I don't find any direct measurements. Do you have good examples and can point me to some published results?

Comment: Second class current decays are suppressed by dint of isospin/G-parity. Go to the PDG,

Comment: Thanks for your help. I searched the PDG. But I failed to find an upper limit for the $\eta$ decay, as well as branching ratios for the $\Delta$ decays. Could you be a bit more precise and / or point me to a specific PDG page / link?

Comment: Tau to eta pi nu is second class. Don’t be stymied by cutting out weak interactions.  Weinberg’s book details such.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There was a typo. I wanted to refer to $\rho^0 \! \to 2\pi^0$ instead of $\eta$. You are right, $\eta \!\to 2\pi^0$ is indeed measured.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with the $\tau \!\to \eta \pi^0 \nu_\tau$ decay? How does isospin conservation enters here?

Comment: For the ρ, no way to compete with $\Gamma_{10}, ~~~ 2\pi^0 \gamma$. You are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: So what you are saying is, that the background $\rho^0 \to 2\pi^0 \gamma$ in $\rho^0 \to 2\pi^0$ is too hard to handle?

Comment: [2nd class currents](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/761/1/012067/pdf) is a separate, long and subtle story. Basically, Weak currents violate C,P, in predictable and precise ways, so *G*-parity violations are purely due to *I* violations. You observe such in the decay cited. Caveat: there is lots of nonsense hidden in the literature on this, however.... In my answer, I got you a clean channel.

Comment: Yes, the EM decay swamps the strong *I*-violating one which is meant to be even weaker!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two nice examples: The Particle Data Group provides a nice [collection of various measurements of the total collision cross-section of $p\pi^\mp$](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/hadronic-xsections/). The $\Delta^0$ and $\Delta^{++}$ peaks are in good agreement with the expected ratio of $1/3$.
The other example is the decay of the $K^+_1(1270)$ into $K^+ \omega$ and $K^+ \rho^0$. Again, the expected ratio is $1/3$, which is in good agreement with the [measurements](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(81)90114-0):
$$\frac{\mathcal{B} \left(K^+_1(1270) \! \to K^+\rho^0 \right)}{\mathcal{B} \left(K^+_1(1270) \!\to K^+\omega \right)} = \frac{0.42 \pm 0.06}{0.11 \pm 0.02} = 3.8 \pm 0.9$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider [J/ψ  ⟶ Λ $\bar Σ^0$ + cc](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.86.032008) , where the J/ψ and Λ are isosinglets and $Σ^0$ is centrally inside an isotriplet.  It is squarely in the [PDG listings](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/listings/rpp2019-list-J-psi-1S.pdf), $\Gamma_{195}$, 28 parts per million.

No external photons are involved, so a bona fide strong isospin violation.

As suggesteded in the comments, from G-violation in 2nd-class weak decays, it is well-understood that the dimensionless violation parameter in the decay amps which enters in the  BRs through its *square* is  $\kappa \approx 10^{-2}$, so, unfortunately, comparable to its EM competitor *α*, in such decays. So the violation  is suppressed by crudely fourish orders of magnitude... put in the high mass products and you are there.

Theoretically, this is interesting, since $\kappa \sim (m_d-m_u)/M$, where the current quark mass difference is 2.5 MeV, while the hadronic scale *M* is $\Lambda_{QCD}$ or, equivalently,  a constituent light quark mass, entering through the currents, so a factor 100 larger.

(This is a major takeaway in understanding why isospin works when it does: it is not that the *u* and *d* quarks are degenerate; hell, one is twice the mass of the other. It is that the masses of both are a small perturbation on the hadronic scales of QCD, so, then, the corresponding baryons *p,n* are almost degenerate.)

So, completely segregating electromagnetism from strong isospin violation is real messy...

Comment: Thanks a lot for these in-depth explanations, much appreciated! Glad that you mention the $J/\psi$ decay, since I never understood the measured branching ratio $J/\psi \to 2\Lambda$ vs $J/\psi \to 2 \Sigma^0$ of ~60%. CG coeffs. give me 1/3 for QCD and even QED (since QED contributes only one diquark, which can then form either $I=1$ or $I=0$, all other quarks are iso-singlets and since $2 \Sigma^0$ can be either $I=2$ or $I=0$, but **not** $I=1$ QED is in that sense also (accidently)  isospin conserving). I cannot belief, that this factor of 2 comes from isospin breaking QCD effects?

Comment: Besides the fact, that your explanation is very helpful, I am still looking for a measurement, where Clebsch-Gordan coeffs. predict roughly the correct branching ratio, similar to my example of the $\Delta$ decays, where I don't find references though, which is quite unfortunate, since I expect QED effects to be quite small here (?).

Comment: I thought that the squared CG coeff, i.e $3$, not $\sqrt{3}$, has to be considered when looking at branching ratios?

Comment: Oh, fair enough, yeah, a factor of 0.6 is not that big of a deal....

Comment: It is the difference between 60% (measured) and 1/3 (CG), i.e. 2x more $\Sigma^0$ than $\Lambda$ than predicted from isospin conservation. I think this is quite large?

Comment: Not really, given details of phase space availability and all kinds of particularities... Possibly deserving its own question; I have no idea how well such Clebschings work across all contexts. But, in the actual question answered we are fussing about *several* orders of magnitude.

Comment: Actually I was asking for cases where CG predict roughly the right branching fractions...

Comment: Oh, I read it as a search for violations, not absence of dynamical corrections to the perfect symmetry limit...

Comment: No, I just want to reference examples where predicting non-zero branching fractions with CG and Isospin conservation actually works. Sorry for being unprecise.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of evidence from nuclear structure. E1 transitions with $\Delta T=0$ are forbidden in $N=Z$ nuclei. We observe isospin multiplets of energy levels, with differences in energy that are small and can be explained from the Coulomb interaction. Direct tests have been made using nucleon-nucleon scattering: https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/0011057